# Invalid number of arguments in Solidity function

Tags: solidity, truffle-contract

Why am I getting **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function**

sol file:

```
uint id  = 1;
    struct Multihash {
        bytes32 digest;
        uint8 hashFunction;
        uint8 size;
    }
    mapping (uint => Multihash) private ipfsHashes;

    function addFile(bytes32 _digest, uint8 _hashFunction, uint8 _size) external {
        Multihash memory entry = Multihash(_digest, _hashFunction, _size);
        ipfsHashes[id] = entry;
        id = id + 1;
    }
```

calling the function is js:

```
storageInstance
        .addFile(digest, hashFunction, size,{ from: account })
        .then(() => {
        });
```

Comment: Make sure all variables hold some value

Comment: Yes, all variables hold some value. It works when I include another parameter for example - 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe your version of the `sol` file and the ABI you are usng in your `js` script aren't corresponding. Try to compile your latest contract and use it in your JS.

Comment: Thank you! One of the parameters was not in the correct format as it was required.